# How to use a Backbone model with jQuery concerning scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, model, scope

I have a jQuery project where I am looking to maintain form data inside model variables. My current UI code is like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#errMsg").hide();

    var Test = Backbone.Model.extend({
            defauts: {
                id: null,
                test: null,
                test1: null,
                test2: null,
                comments: null
            }
        });

     var uniquename = new Test({ id: null});


});

function test(){
  //Trying to access uniquename here or Test model
}
```

When I try to access either Test or uniquename from the method outside, they're not accessible. All the other stuff I do is inside plain Javascript methods. I know this is not the right way to do it so i'm seeking some help. How do I structure my methods and how do I make my variables accessible across different methods so I can read the web service response from one method and use that as a request for another method?

Answer (score 1):

Simply define the function inside the same scope:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#errMsg").hide();

  var Test = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defauts: {
            id: null,
            test: null,
            test1: null,
            test2: null,
            comments: null
        }
    });

    var uniquename = new Test({ id: null});
    function test(){
       //access uniquename here or Test model
    }
});
```

If you can't do that, for example if your code is split into different files or something, then simplest solution would be to use name spaces - like `MyApp.Models.Test = Backbone.Model.extend({})`. `MyApp` in this case will be globally available (declared outside `$(document).ready()` in the file that is loaded first )

or use module pattern, RequireJS is pretty common module loader in Backbone.js applications.

Comment: When I put test() inside the jQuery scope, I wasn't able to do <Button onclick="test();">. How do I get around that?

Comment: @p0tta Don't use inline event handlers. You have jQuery, so use jQuery to add events, like `$('#myButtonsId').click(test);`

Comment: True. That makes sense. Not sure why I didn't think of that. Thanks!

Comment: So I did that and it doesn't seem to work. I get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined
    at backbone.js:382
    at backbone.js:31
    at backbone.js:31
(anonymous) @ backbone.js:382
(anonymous) @ backbone.js:31
(anonymous) @ backbone.js:31
initial.js:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

Comment: I have a mix of JSP, jQuery and Javascript so unfortunately I have plain JS functions to deal with as well.

Comment: @p0tta I'm not sure what exactly is the problem you're facing, but then maybe use need to have a global namespace